# select row that have the most values and show them

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image: Text]
Hi guys !

I have tables like this, and i need to select Harcerze.Imie,Harcerze.Nazwisko,Sprawnosc.Nazwa_sprawnosci
for that Id_harcerza that have the most Id_sprawnosci and show them with their names (Nazwa_sprawnosci)

So output should looks like this: (its example data) if two rows have the same amount so show both

```
Imie  | Nazwisko | Nazwa_sprawnosci

Maciej  Linux      ratownik
Maciej  Linux      zeglarz
Maciej  Linux      goral
Maciej  Linux      tropiciel
Maciej  Linux      strzelec
Maciej  Linux      goral
```

Edit.
I am using MS Access 2019.

Relationships are :

Harcerze.Id_harcerza(PK) to Dzialania.Id_harcerza

Sprawnosc.Id_sprawnosci(PK) to Dzialania.Id_sprawnosci

Comment: I see no relationship between the desired results and the sample data.  You should also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I edited post with additional informations

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the users that have logged/submitted the most of a category, where records with the same category grouped. The records are then ordered in descending order.

To understand this I mapped the tables to a familiar set of tables.

I make the following mappings:

```
Harcerze => Users
Sprawnosc => DeviceType
Dzailania => AuditLog

Harcerze.Imie,Harcerze.Nazwisko => a user name
Sprawnosc.Nazwa_sprawnosci => a device type (the category to be grouped)
```

I define the following tables:

```
Users (ID int, Name char(10));
DeviceType (ID, DeviceType char(10));
AuditLog (ID int, DateLogged date, UserID int, DeviceTypeID int);
```

Sample data:

```
DELETE FROM DeviceType;    
INSERT INTO DeviceType VALUES (1, 'Mobile');    
INSERT INTO DeviceType VALUES (2, 'Tablet');    
INSERT INTO DeviceType VALUES (3, 'Desktop');

DELETE FROM Users;    
INSERT INTO Users VALUES (1, 'Steve');    
INSERT INTO Users VALUES (2, 'May');    
INSERT INTO Users VALUES (3, 'Peter');    
INSERT INTO Users VALUES (4, 'Alice');    
INSERT INTO Users VALUES (5, 'William');

DELETE FROM AuditLog;    
INSERT INTO AuditLog VALUES (1, '2021-05-01', 1, 1);    
INSERT INTO AuditLog VALUES (2, '2021-05-02', 2, 2);    
INSERT INTO AuditLog VALUES (3, '2021-05-03', 3, 3);    
INSERT INTO AuditLog VALUES (4, '2021-05-04', 1, 2);    
INSERT INTO AuditLog VALUES (5, '2021-05-06', 2, 1);    
INSERT INTO AuditLog VALUES (6, '2021-05-10', 4, 1);    
INSERT INTO AuditLog VALUES (7, '2021-05-12', 5, 2);    
INSERT INTO AuditLog VALUES (8, '2021-05-15', 1, 3);    
INSERT INTO AuditLog VALUES (9, '2021-05-16', 1, 2);    
INSERT INTO AuditLog VALUES (10, '2021-05-16', 4, 2);
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT w.[Name], total_logins=SUM(w.[num_logs])
FROM 
   (SELECT u.[Name], d.[DeviceType], num_logs=COUNT(d.[DeviceType])
    FROM   AuditLog a
    JOIN   Users u ON u.ID = a.UserID
    JOIN   DeviceType d ON d.ID = a.DeviceTypeID
    GROUP BY u.[Name], d.[DeviceType]) w
GROUP BY w.[Name]
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Output:

```
Name        total_logins
----
Steve       4
Alice       2
May         2
Peter       1
William     1
```

I hope this is useful in SQL as I haven't used Access for very very long time.

Comment: Thanks for help but i need a little bit different scenario.

i need to Output that user with the most 'logins'  and show the logins

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs a reply to my post here, I did it myself after a few hours

```
SELECT TOP 2 t.imie,t.nazwisko,Nazwa_sprawnosci
  FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT Dzialania.Id_sprawnosci,Harcerze.Imie,Harcerze.Nazwisko
  FROM  Dzialania,Sprawnosc,Harcerze WHERE Dzialania.Id_sprawnosci=Sprawnosc.Id_sprawnosci AND Harcerze.Id_harcerza=Dzialania.Id_harcerza
  ) t,Sprawnosc
GROUP BY t.imie,t.nazwisko,nazwa_sprawnosci
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```